# How to make a search engine using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

My problem is that I have to make a search engine like Gmail's compose mail. There when we type in the email id it searches our contact list and shows the searched results.

I was able to search the database for the emails but I cannot append any one of those searched email to the textbox it is searched in.

My code:

- [index.html](http://pastebin.com/8ZWpe1yg)
- [jquery](http://pastebin.com/9BhCeb6d)
- [search.php](http://pastebin.com/3iKJSD9S)

Comment: maybe you should post your code.

Comment: This question is quite general. Can you be more specific with what part of the code is causing a problem?

Comment: Apparently you're using some server-side code to run your queries, so I assume this is an issue that AJAX can solve for, but we're going to need more information.

Comment: index.html http://pastebin.com/8ZWpe1yg

Comment: my problem is i am appending the email ids but instead of just one email id it is appending the whole list of email id it fetched from database

Comment: jquery file http://pastebin.com/9BhCeb6d

Comment: search.php file http://pastebin.com/3iKJSD9S

Comment: i think its some problem with the div placement i made

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are trying to do that, but i would suggest [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: Expand the View Source to see an example?